# How can I track button click in google analitycs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, onclick, tags

I had register my website in the google analytics and I had put the script in my default index like this :

```
<html> 

<head>

    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="****************" />

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-7**4*7***"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-7**4*7***');
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<a class="" href="/Contents/Make-App">
    <div class="text">Make app</div>
</a>
...
<script src="/Content/assets/script/combined.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*4**0**6-*"></script>

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-*4**0**6-*');
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want if I click button "make app", it will be listed on Google Analytics. so I can see how many people clicked on that button

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure events through the google tag manager console. This post might help. https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/google-tag-manager-button-click-tracking